# Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Canvas' to type 'Canvas'

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a `canvas` and want to get its name when it is `Tapped`. So, I have this `XAML`:

```
<Canvas Name="drawLine" ... >
...
</Canvas>
```

and this function bind on `Tapped` event:

```
private void ChangePage(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
     string name = ((Canvas)sender).Name.ToString();
     Frame.Navigate(typeof(Params), name);
}
```

bug get the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in
>   gotqn.exe but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Canvas' to type 'gotqn.Canvas'.

Why `((Canvas)sender).Name.ToString();` is generating such error? Is there other way to get the name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you have two Canvas classes in different namespaces. I guess the `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls` namespace is not in your `using` so the code is assuming `gotqn.Canvas`. Did you declare your own Canvas class? If yes, you may have to specify the full name of the Canvas class you want

```
string name = ((Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Canvas)sender).Name.ToString();
```

Comment: Ah... I have created a second page called `Canvas`. It seems that this was causing the issue, as I  have deleted the page end it was resolved.